# Getting values from nested JSON document

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get values from a nested JSON document. I wrote the following function:

```
var jsondata = {
'name': {
    'fname': 'Jack',
    'lname': [{'familyName': 'Sparrow'}, {'surname': 'Captain'}]
    }
};

var extracted = get_value(jsondata, 'familyName');
console.log(extracted); // null is getting printed

function get_value(dataObject, keyName) {
    value = null;

    for (var i in dataObject) {
        if (i == keyName) {
            value = dataObject[keyName];
            console.log(value); // getting correct value of 'familyName' here
            return value;
        } else if (typeof dataObject[i] == 'object') {
        get_value(dataObject[i], keyName);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting the correct value when printing `console.log(value);`, but `null` is getting printed by `console.log(extracted);`. Its like a return inside the for-in loop is not actually exiting the loop when the value is found.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it should be name.lname.familyname  try it out once. @Sparky

Comment: Thanks @Kira, that kind of access will work, but I was trying more of a dynamic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I rewrote the code and now it will return the value of any given key in the json data:-

```
function get_value_nested(dataObject, keyName) {
    var value = null;
    this.get_value = function (dataObject, keyName) {
        for (i in dataObject) {
            if (i == keyName) {
                value = dataObject[keyName];
            } else if (typeof dataObject[i] == 'object') {
                 this.get_value(dataObject[i], keyName);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    this.get_value(dataObject, keyName);

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function you need to assign the value returned by `get_value`:

```
get_value(dataObject[i], keyName);
```

Should be:

```
value = get_value(dataObject[i], keyName);
```

Alternatively, just return the value:

```
return get_value(dataObject[i], keyName);
```

Comment: Aah, that worked with the initial problem. But failed to work when I tried `get_value(jsondata, 'surname');` instead of `get_value(jsondata, 'familyName');`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `value = null;` from the function.

Comment: Then it will give `undefined` :)